# Composer: how to add multiple Git projects to "require"?

Tags: git, composer-php

I have several projects (`foo/bar`, `foo/baz`, `foo/xyz`) on GitHub. I would like to `require` them into my other projects. For example in `composer.json`:

```
"require": {
    "foo/bar": "2.*",
    "foo/baz": "1.0.*"
}
```

If I setup `repositories` as:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/foo/bar"
    }
],
```

...then I can only `require` the `foo/bar` and `foo/baz` is not found obviously. How can I import them both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I'm answering my own question.** This is what works for me:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Foo/Bar"
    },
    {
        "type": "vcs",
        "url": "https://github.com/Foo/Baz"
    }
],
"require": {
    "foo/bar": "2.*",
    "foo/baz": "1.0.*"
}
```

Now, composer while updating search for `foo/bar` in repositories and if it finds it (in this case in the first repository), downloads it. Then, for `foo/baz` does the same thing, but it finds it in the second repository.